# Companion object в Kotlin

Tags: тестирование, junit, kotlin

Только перехожу с Java на Kotlin. Возник вопрос, ответ на который, к сожалению, я не смог найти.
Существует некий абстрактный класс с несколькими абстрактными переменными, на который потом будут ложиться десятки тестов. Тестирую с помощью JUnit. Методы аннотированные `@BeforeClass` и `@AfterClass` обязаны быть статичными, и я вижу только один способ разрешения пробелемы: запихнуть методы внутрь `companion object`, где можно использовать `@JvmStatic`, но при этом, в методе `@BeforeClass` вызывается абстрактная переменная, задаваемая каждой реализацией отдельно. Соответсвенно, каким образом можно обратиться к переменной из внешнего класса? Или может быть есть другой способ разрешения такой задачи? Код:

```
abstract class TemplateConfig {

    abstract val template : String?


    companion object {
        lateinit var h: Handle

        @BeforeClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun setUp() {
            h = dbi.value.open()
            //Здесь используется абстрактная переменная
            //
            //if (template != null) {
            //    h.createStatement(template).execute()
            //}
        }

        @AfterClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun tearDown() {
            h.close()
        }

        //{...Объявление и инициализация других переменных...}
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554076/how-do-i-manage-unit-test-resources-in-kotlin-such-as-starting-stopping-a-datab

Comment: @rjhdby Спасибо, конечно, но это я и сам находил, и на мой вопрос это никак не отвечает.

Comment: В целом ответы сходятся к "Don't put the BeforeClass on the abstract class. Call it from each subclass."

Comment: @rjhdby похоже, что так. Альтернатив нет? Ибо писать одно и тоже в двух десятках тестовых классов не очень удобно.

Comment: А зачем abstract у template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы пытаетесь в статическом методе обратиться к нестатической переменной/методу которая задается в классе потомке. Так не выйдет. Единственное решение, которое я вижу, это определить поле статическим и при инициализации класса-потомка задать ему значение.

```
object Demo {
   protected var value:String
   @BeforeClass
   fun setUp() {
      println(value)
   }
   @AfterClass
   fun destroy() {
   }
}
internal class SubClass:Demo() {
   companion object {
     init {
        Demo.value = "this is value"
     }
   }
}
```